# How to implement OpenID (Single Sign On) for Spring Boot JAVA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, single-sign-on, openid

I did go through https://openid.net/ but not able to understand how to implement this for creating and maintaining single sign on feature. Do let me know if anyone has found proper documentation or tutorial to implement this in java spring boot.

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't support OpenID Connect. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the Baeldung Tutorial on [Spring Security and OpenID Connect](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect). If you use the identity provider of your ecosystem, this will also bring the single-sign-on feature alongside.

E.g. if you connect your `spring-boot` application to the Google identity provider via `oauth2`/`oidc`, then you will not be prompted your credentials again, if you are already logged in to other Google service in your current browser session.